# ssh-keygen -t rsa1 is failing

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-keygen

On Ubuntu 18.04

`ssh-keygen -t rsa1` is failing with: `unknown key type rsa1`.

However when typing `ssh-keygen -t rsa` auto-complete gives me two options:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
rsa   rsa1
```

How can I generate an rsa1 key?

Comment: Why try to work around a deprecated security method?

Comment: Because it is required from an old kernel module (not supported any more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around since rsa1 seems to be deprecated (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/226131/openssh-declares-ssh-rsa-deprecated-what-do-i-do-next)

I installed **openssh-client-ssh1** with:
`sudo apt install openssh-client-ssh1`

and now I can succesfully execute `ssh-keygen1 -t rsa1`.